two different function pointer calls with the same value returning in C
Here we have two function pointer calls that assigned the returned values to variables in different ways.
int *func()
{
    int *i = calloc(2, sizeof(int));
    *i = 100;
    *(i + 1) = 200;
    printf("i address: %p\n", i);
    return i; // or 0, both represent a null pointer
}

int main()
{
    int(*(*x)())[20] = &func;
    int *i = (*x)();
    int *p = *(*x)();
    printf("%d\n", *p);
    printf("%d\n", *i);

    return 0;
}

The code outputs:
i address: <some address>
i address: <some address>
100
100

I expected int *p = *(*x)(); printf("%d\n", *p); to raise an error.
Why do these two different calls output the same value?

Instead of using so much pointers and dereferencing, please use array indexing when valid. Like instead of *i or *(i + 1) use i[0] and i[1]. That's just makes more sense and is much easier to read and understand. Same thing with x.

And on the note of making things more readable (and therefore easier to understand and maintain), please use type-aliases for pointers to functions. Like typedef int *(*function_type)(void);. Then declaring an array of that is as simple as function_type x[20];'

@Someprogrammerdude Thank you for the suggestions. This code is just for figuring out how complex pointer statements work.

The thing here is that functions decay to pointers to themselves. So plain func will decay to &func. Therefore it doesn't matter if you dereference a pointer to a function or not, it will still be a pointer to the function.

@Someprogrammerdude I just modified the int(*(*x)())[20] = &func; to int(*(*x)())[20] = func; and the result remains intact.

Your types are messed up. Turn up your warning/error levels. Compiler says: "warning: initialization of 'int (* (*)(void))[20]' from incompatible pointer type 'int * (*)(void)'" and "warning: initialization of 'int *' from incompatible pointer type 'int (*)[20]'"

@Someprogrammerdude I interpret the line int *p = *(*x)(); as: point to the address the variable x is pointing. then call the function. afterwards point to the returned value. Since the returned value is address of value 100, the variable p should be assigned to value 100, is this correct?

Your compiler should have warned you. If it didn't, you need to upgrade or switch to a different compiler. If it did, you shouldn't ever try to run the program, but fix it so that it compiles cleanly. See this.

@AviBerger Yes, I have compiled the code with the -Wall flag. but the point of question is understanding the difference of the two different assignments. Thanks for your finesse.

The expression *(*x)() is equivalent to (*(x[0]))(). So it takes the first element of x. Dereferences the pointer to the function (which as I mentioned above doesn't really do anything), and then calls the function.

I wouldn't call it finesse. func does not return a pointer to an array of 20 ints. x is of the wrong type to use with it.

@Someprogrammerdude So you are saying the *(*x)() just calls the function, not pointing the the value function returns, right? I just tried int *p = (****x)(); and it seems it doesn't matter how many time you use pointers to reach the function. does this expression  int *p = *((*x)()); confirm the way I interpreted the statement? It should de-reference pointer the function returns

@Someprogrammerdude it does not mean array of 20 function pointers

There's no need to "turn up some warning levels" on a conforming C compiler. int(*(*x)())[20] = &func; is simply invalid C and so the compiler must give a diagnostic message or it is non-conforming and shouldn't be used.

@Lundin wrong dupe as * is derefeencing the array of ints and it does not have anything in common with function pointers from the dupe

@gulpr Well I guess it should have been closed as unclear then, because we can't speculate about how to interpret (*(*x)() for a function of unknown type... is it an array pointer, is it a plain int pointer. The OP needs to start by posting valid, compiling C code and then maybe we can salvage it from there.

@Lundin No - the return type is well known. it returns pointer to  int array.  Read carefully the declaration. I know that they can be sometimes difficult to read adn uinderstand

@gulpr x returns a pointer to an int array but the function returns an int*. Calling a function with the wrong function pointer type is wildly UB and the assignment is plain invalid C.

x pointer return type is well-defined by its declaration. When you call function referenced by x you will get a pointer to array of 20 ints

@Lundin but it is not related to the dupe. Dupe is misleading

Now for the love of unclear questions can @shayanrokrok kindly fix the code so that it actually compiles cleanly without C language constraint violations? And in the meantime can everyone else close this as unclear or lacking minimal example? Speculating what will happen when UB is invoked in some code written in the "not C" language isn't interesting neither for the OP nor future readers.

@Lundin The provided C code is compiled with warnings but without any errors. So I think it's better to compile the code by yourself so you confirm the code is working.
What's your definition of unclear? because I have seen questions with similar syntax and it was unclear to nobody. So MAYBE THE CODE IS NOT THE PROBLEM.
indeed the purpose of the question is not reforming the code, ChatGPT can do the job :)))

@shayanrokrok You are under the misconception that warnings are some sort of minor trifle that can be ignored. In this case they mean "this code here is not valid C so what will happen with the program if you ignore the warning is anyone's guess". See What must a C compiler do when it finds an error?

@shayanrokrok Specifically, the code is a constraint violation against C's rules of assignment. In C, you cannot assign a pointer to a non-compatible pointer, simple as that.

@Lundin Why isn't incompatible type defined as an error instead of a warning?
Why the compiler doesn't prevent it? since it's a "constraint violation against C's rules of assignment". All the "incompatible type" warnings are included as Undefined Behavior? As you can use correct func return value and use int *i = (*x)(); and it prints out the same. Could you please bring the official C specification reference document link?

@shayanrokrok Ask the people who made the compiler. It is utter nonsense to let things like this slip through into a binary executable and yet they let it happen. This would be a constraint violation as per C17 6.5.16.1 "- the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer type, and (considering the type
the left operand would have after lvalue conversion) both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types, and the type pointed to by the left has all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right;"

@Lundin I think you just keep missing the fact that I KNOW THIS IS NOT A TOTALLY STABLE CODE. I know how to make it solid but the question is made to figure out how things works with the code as it is.

@Lundin  BTW, thank you for the provided information and link that links to some compiler arguments.

Nothing complicated and secret in this code.
int(*(*x)())[20] means "declare x as pointer to function returning pointer to array 20 of int elements"*
Two UBs:

int(*(*x)())[20] = &func; - func is not returning pointer to array 20 ints  (basically it has the wrong type)
int *i = (*x)(); as you initialize pointer to int with pointer to array of ints. Those pointers are not compatible.


Why do these two different calls output the same value?


(*x)() returns pointer to array of 20 ints. It is assigned ti an array to int (which is an UB). On your platform both have the same format and you get the address of the first element of this array. Bear in mind that the function assigned to x pointer has a wrong type and it is separate Undefined Behaviour
int *p = *(*x)() can be split into two operations"

int (*arr)[20] = (*x)();
int *p = *arr;

The second line gives an array of 20 ints which decays to a pointer to int which is assigned to p. p references the first element of that array.

Of course either the x declaration or the func return type must be changed for a warning-proof code. In your example, it's expected for arr to hold a pointer to array of 20 int values. but (*x)() is actually returning a int*. So *arr gives 100 then the value of int *p should be 100. How *(*x)() and (*x)() doesn't make any difference?

Another way to bring the question is:
   int i = 100;     int *p = &i;     int(*arrp)[2] = p;     printf("%p\n", p);     printf("%p\n", arrp);     printf("%p\n", *arrp);
(I know the arrp is incompatible type) this code snippet has similar functionality. the output of three printf lines is identical. is it included as Undefined Behavior?

@shayanrokrok (*x)() IS NOT RETURNING INT.

I said it returns int*,  NOT int.

@shayanrokrok it DOES NOT return int * only int (*)20!

First, let's create an function that is actually compatible with the type of x.
int a[20] = { ... };

// Function that returns a pointer to an array of 20 `int` objects.
int (*func())[20] { return &a; }

// Pointer to a function that returns a pointer to an array of 20 `int` objects.
int(*(*x)())[20] = func;

That's crazy hard to read. Let's replaces it with easier to read but equivalent code.
typedef int Int20Array[20];
typedef Int20Array *Int20Function( void );

int a[20] = { ... };

Int20Array *func() { return &a; }

Int20Function *x = func;


On to the question. Let's look at
int *p = *(*x)();

This is equivalent to
int *p = *&a;

*& cancels out.
int *p = a;

An array degrades into a pointer to its first element.
int *p = &a[0];

printf("%d\n", *p); therefore prints the value of the first element of the "returned" array.

Now, let's look at
int *i = (*x)();

This is equivalent to
int *i = &a;

Here we assign a pointer to an array of int objects to a pointer to an int object. This isn't valid and produces a warning.
But in reality, they are compatible since a pointer to an array is really a pointer to its first element except in type. So the above is effectively equivalent to
int *i = &a[0];

printf("%d\n", *i); therefore prints the value of the first element of the "returned" array.

About int *i = &a;, do you mean the compiler automatically converts it to int *i = &a[0];? If so, I think this rule also applies for function pointers. I appreciate your explanation. I wanted to figure out the functionality when the x declaration is as in the question. I mean when the func returns int* instead of int(*)[20] type.

Re "do you mean the compiler automatically convert", I'm saying &a and &a[0] return pointers (of different types) to the same address, so your bad &a is at the machine level the same as &a[0].

With your original func, it's the same error and quasi-equivalence as explained in the previous comment. You're illegally pretending a pointer to an array and a pointer to the first element of an array are compatible, but it works since they have the same address. I didn't cover that in that answer, because you asked why the output is the same despite the differences, so the content of func wasn't relevant and the fact that it was undefined behaviour just complicated things.
